# Restarting the python debugger, pdb, while propagating program changes

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

I am debugging a python program using the python debugger pdb.

E.g. `python -m pdb myscript.py`

Is there a way to rerun the script propagating the new changes in myscript.py?  The command `run` does not do this.

In gdb, I believe there was a way to compile (from within gdb) and the restart the debugging session.

I was hoping for a similar feature in pdb, so that I do not need to exit pdb and then start it again just to get my changes in `myscript.py` to be propagated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `run`, or `restart`, which is an alias of `run`. This will restart the program with all the new changes but preserve the breakpoints and other debugger information.

Comment: Modules will not be reloaded.